# Is this a gerund phrase after hate?

Tags: parts-of-speech, gerunds

"I hate not being able to control my temper."

From my understanding, hate is one of those verbs that is followed by a gerund OR an infinitive. In this situation, is "being" a gerund?

> From EF.com https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/using-hate-love/
> the verbs "to hate", "to like", and "to love"
> The verbs hate, love, like, & prefer are usually followed by a gerund when the meaning is general, and by the infinitive when they refer to a particular time or situation. You must always use the infinitive with the expressions would love to, would hate to, etc. These verbs can also be followed by a that-clause or by a noun.

Comment: The gerund phrase "not being able to control my temper" is used exactly as a noun would be: "I hate [broccoli][injustice][the way my shoes fit][not being able to control my temper]" and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*being* in this case heads a gerund-participial clause. It has the internal structure of a complex-intransitive clause with adjunct *not*.

> (*my/me*) [understood subject]
>
> *not* [adjunct - negation]
>
> *being* [verb at the head of the clause]
>
> *able to control my temper* [subjective predicative complement]

These are also known as *-ing* clauses or present participle clauses depending on who you ask. *The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* p217

> ***-ing clause*** A non-finite clause whose verb phrase contains a verb ending in -ing as its head. Also called ***present participle
> clause***, ***-ing participle clause***, and ***gerund-participial
> clause***. Examples:
>
> The boss hates ***him always complaining about everything***
>
> I love ***working late***
>
> Notice that the first example contains its own subject, whereas the
> second example does not.